# Comparar dos fechas en Postgress

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, yii2

en el entorno de yii2 framework quiero seleccionar aquellos campos cuya fecha sea mayor de la la fecha actual (TimeStamp de php), para ello tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT f.*, f.id as identificador, usuarios.* FROM usuarios INNER JOIN feeds f ON usuarios.id = f.usuariosid
        GROUP BY f.id, usuarios.id having usuarios.id=1 or f.created_at = ' . date(Y-m-d,time();
```

El campo created_at es tipo date-timeStamp en la tabla y almacena la fecha con el siguiente formato: 2020-04-13 14:16:40
La anterior consulta, me arroja el siguiente error:You might need to add explicit type casts.

Si realizo este  casting:

```
'SELECT f.*, f.id as identificador, usuarios.* FROM usuarios INNER JOIN feeds f ON usuarios.id = f.usuariosid
            GROUP BY f.id, usuarios.id having usuarios.id=1 or f.created_at > cast(' . date('Y-m-d') . ' as date)';
```

Me devuelve:

SQLSTATE[42846]: Cannot coerce: 7 ERROR: cannot cast type integer to date
LINE 2: ... usuarios.id having usuarios.id=1 or created_at > cast(2020-...

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Gracias

Agrego la definición de las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
username varchar(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
contrasena varchar(255),
auth_key varchar(255),
nombre varchar(255) NOT NULL,
apellidos varchar(255) NOT NULL,
email varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
url_avatar varchar(255),
direccion varchar(255),
localidad varchar(255),
estado varchar(255),
fecha_nac date,
token_acti VARCHAR(255),
codigo_verificacion VARCHAR(255),
ultima_conexion timestamp,
fecha_alta timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
CREATE TABLE feeds (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    usuariosid bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES usuarios(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    contenido varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    imagen varchar(255),
    created_at timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp
);
```

Comment: si agregas a tu pregunta la definición de tus tablas podemos ayudarte mejor, así es más fácil cuál es mejor castear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente el error que tienes se debe a que estás usando un int para compararlo con un string. No necesitas hacer ningún cast para tu variable date('Y-m-d'):

```
<?php
$date = '2018-11-11';
echo 'SELECT f.*, f.id as identificador, usuarios.* FROM usuarios INNER JOIN feeds f ON usuarios.id = f.usuariosid
            GROUP BY f.id, usuarios.id having usuarios.id=1 or f.created_at > \'' . date('Y-m-d') . '\';';
?>
```

eso podría bien escribir lo siguiente como resultado:

```
SELECT f.*, f.id as identificador, usuarios.* FROM usuarios INNER JOIN feeds f ON usuarios.id = f.usuariosid
        GROUP BY f.id, usuarios.id having usuarios.id=1 or f.created_at > '2020-04-13';
```

Te recomiendo revisar un poco sobre la documentación de escapar strings en PHP y la comparación de dates en SQL.

saludos.